# how to add draggable functionality on a div when using a template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I want to add draggable functionality on a div at runtime. The div's id is generated with the following code:

```
var Exp=0;
view.renderFunction = function(id1){
  var id= id1 + Exp++;
  $("#"+id).draggable();
};
```

This is my function where the id is dynamically generated when I drop div. 
But when I apply the draggable method it can't move. How can I move div?

Comment: `draggable` is a single word, correct it, somehow I am not seeing the edit option in the question.

Comment: added a fiddle to my answer, check it, its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used kinetic.js and now it working fine

Answer (score 2):

It will work, have tested this.

Make sure of the following points:

- Make sure you know what is Exp++ (you haven't mentioned about it in the question)
- The element on which you call draggable() is a valid DOM element.
- Try calling it on document ready or DOM ready

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gopi1410/ByWCS/

Answer (score 2):

Are you facing trouble with dragging itself or is the problem only with dropping it anywhere? This should be pretty straight forward. Here is a sample that shows dragging a child div from one parent div to another:
[How to enable dragging a div from one parent div to another](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-enable-dragging-a-div-from-one-parent-div-and-dropping-into-another-parent-div/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var id= id1 + Exp++; 
$("#"+id).draggable();
```

What is `Exp++`, and are you sure that you are calling `.draggable()` on an existing element? Also, is that renderFunction ever called with an id?